# How can I clean my software caches from the command line?

Tags: command-line, cache

In the upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 I lost the ability to use Ubuntu Tweak's Janitor to clean caches so I would like to know how to do it from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used any such software but if you're talking about caches, I think you might mean downloaded APT packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives` which are cleaned with `sudo apt-get clean`.

If you mean package/source package caches, then these can be re-generated with `apt-cache gencaches`. If you want to remove them for some (odd) reason, they're held in:

```
/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin
/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
```

Comment: Nope `sudo apt-get clean` only cleans the apt cache not software cache.

Comment: Software cache is a rather non-specific term to be honest - I'm aware what that command does :) Just curious - why do you feel you need to manage this manually or with the help of some tweak package?

Answer (score 0):

Install BleachBit.  It will clean your /var//var/cache/apt/archives when you run BleachBit as root.
I use BB every nite to clean up install/upgrade downloads.